# Primitive integral of $a/(x^2 + a^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate the following: $$\displaystyle \int \frac{a}{x^2+a^2} dx$$

I made an approach by substitution $\displaystyle \gamma = \frac{x}{a}$ and ended up with $\displaystyle  \arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$, is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed, the answer is correct, but the [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) would ultimately need to be $\gamma = \dfrac xa = \tan\theta$, or $\theta = \arctan\left(\dfrac xa\right)$, whether that substitution is made directly, or indirectly from the integral formula for integrands of that form which relies upon that substitution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac a{a^2+x^2}=\frac1a\frac1{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}\implies$$

$$\int\frac a{a^2+x^2}dx=\int\frac{\frac1adx}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2}=\ldots$$

Now use the general fact (that you shoud prove, for example using the chain rule)

$$\int\frac{f'(x)dx}{1+f(x)^2}=\arctan f(x)+C$$